# Getting users list from an AD Group

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I have a domain and I am not aware of the domain server name or IPaddress, all I know is just the domain name. A group created under this domain. The users added to this domain belong to different domains. I have to get the list of users, irrespective of their domain, added to that group and show it in a list box. I have to do this in C# web application.

Please direct me.

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET 3.5 and the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, you should be able to write something like:

```
// create domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// fetch your group
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "groupname");

// enumerate over the group's members
foreach (Principal p in group.Members)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Principal '{0}', type '{1}'", p.Name, p.StructuralObjectClass);
}
```

This should list all the member's of that group (users and groups).